# How to communicate over I2C in Windows?

Tags: windows, usb

In Linux, one can use the `i2c-tools` package to interact with i2c devices, be this by using a computer's integrated I2C controller (as found on laptop SODIMMs) or using generic external "USB-to-I2C" adapters. Given one or the other option, how can a Windows user achieve the same?

I know of an expensive National Instruments gadget that can be programmed in LabView to communicate over I2C, but I was thinking more in the direction of generic USB-to-I2C breakout boards. I have had thoughts about using Docker/Putty with one USB-to-UART and one UART-to-I2C converter but that just seems unpractical (if it would work at all).

Comment: A USB-to-I2C breakout board would need a board-specific driver, both in Windows and Linux. Specific USB-to-I2C chips may already have drivers in Linux. The existence of an I2C kernel API (also in `/proc`) doesn't guarantee it will work with any kind of hardware.

Comment: Most if not all vendors provide drivers (some are royalty-free, even!), and Device Manager recognizes the adapters as having something to do with I2C. I do believe the hardware is working, but I'm completely baffled as to how to _use_ the hardware with my operating system. Say I have a simple Arduino sensor or display and what to send a command over to it -- Why must this be so difficult with I2C devices, when UART communication is so very simple.

Comment: To provide an example, Keterex makes the USB-910H. It costs $200 but the software it comes with is practically useless, albeit available for Windows. I doubt a company would offer a $200 device that you could only use with their free but oversimplified program.

Comment: So you are looking for the Windows API to access those drivers? I do not know, but I wouldn't be surprised if this was different per driver. For example, a driver could pretend to be a serial device, with a special protocol to access the I2C part.

Comment: I'm ... looking for software to interact with the hardware adapters I have. Like Docklight or Putty for UART, or at least a CLI software like Linux's i2c-tools. I'm guessing the drivers have to be generic to some extent if the PC's intenal hardware includes an I2C line, but you're getting way too specific here for me. I'm just a guy with a bunch of I2C dongles, some of them very expensive, and a Windows computer, trying to ge them to work together.

Answer (score 0):

For USB-910H, vendor provides "USB-900 Control Center" software.

I don't think there any generic windows software to access I2C. However every vendor provides their C (or .NET API) to access the device.

For USB-910H, see the datasheet
https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/214/kxusb910hds-1396.pdf

and their applications notes:

1. Application Note AN2101 - The USB-910H API and Include File Reference Manual.
2. Application Note AN2102 - The USB-900 Control Center User's Guide.